# Is Possible to convert image file to binary format in Javascript.

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, web-sql

how to convert image file to binary format in Javascript. I can not get a solution for this. Please explain Is this possible or not?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript

Comment: An image file *is* binary. What exactly do you want to convert?

Comment: The dup assumes locally loaded files. The answers are outdated and one doesn't produce binary format (data-uri). OP should consider providing more info though.

Answer (score 1):

The image file at the moment is a binary image data (png, jpg, gif etc), if your question was directed to ask about conversion to a base64 encoded string then the best way is to use HTML5 canvas for your conversion, below is a given function that can be used at your disposal:

```
function toDataUrl(url, callback, outputFormat){
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var dataURL;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.width = this.width;
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
        callback(dataURL);
        canvas = null; 
    };
    img.src = url;
}
```

Then you can call:

```
toDataUrl(imageURLString, function(base64Img){
    // Base64DataURL
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Load the image using `XMLHttpRequest`. This will avoid having to go through canvas. CORS restrictions apply to both so the only difference is that with `XMLHttpRequest` you can load the data directly as `ArrayBuffer` or a `Blob`.

```js
// Load image via XMLHttpRequest
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();                       // create a "loader"
xhr.open("GET", "https://i.imgur.com/9LqhOl3b.jpg");  // url, CORS apply (!)
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";                     // or "blob"
xhr.onerror = alert;                                  // use error handler here
xhr.onload = function() {                             // async onload handler
  if (xhr.status === 200) process(xhr.response);      // All OK
  else alert("Error:" + xhr.statusText);              // oops...
};
xhr.send();                                           // send request

// Now we can access it through typed array wo/ canvas
function process(buffer) {

  var view = new Uint8Array(buffer);                  // access bytes through a view
  console.log("Content:", view[0], view[1], view[2], view[3], ".. etc..");
  
  // convert to blob and show
  var blob = new Blob([view], {type: "image/jpeg"});
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var img = new Image;
  img.src = url;
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

```html
Loading...<br>
```